# Why do I get "'numpy.dtype' object is not callable" in pandas when I applymap(type)

Tags: pandas

I wanted to observe, what types I have in my dataframe, because I got a message, that states, that in some cell there is a tuple, where there should be none.
Ok, I know I could figure out where it is otherwise, but during investigation I encountered another problem, that leaves me puzzled.

I wanted to do

```
df.applymap(type).melt()
```

Then aggregate this to get a type-count, but even the first step with the `applymap(type)` raises an error that I don't understand:

```
"'numpy.dtype' object is not callable", 'occurred at index building_id'
```

What is this cryptinc message trying to tell me?

My dataframe has the following columns:

```
building_id                    int32
primary_use                    int64
square_feet                    int32
year_built                     int32
day_index                      int64
hour                           int64
meter_0.0                      float32
meter_1.0                      float32
cloud_coverage                 float64
dew_temperature                float64
precip_depth_1_hr              float64
sea_level_pressure             float64
wind                           float64
wind_north                     float64
energy_heat                    float64
energy_cool                    float64
date_year                      int64
period_type                    int64
num_days_period                int64
num_days_change                int64
num_days_next_period           int64
```

Nothing fancy, right? btw. the tuple certainly is not included in the `df` with the columns above. I just have a framework, that builds the dataframe on-the-fly based on a configuration, and if at all, then the tuple is created in another configuration, however with the dataframe above, I get the error stated above.

Any ideas, what causes the error and how I can fix it?

Because this is probably one of the first questions, the versions I am using, are:

```
pd.__version__
Out[150]: '0.25.0'

np.__version__
Out[151]: '1.17.4'
```

Edit: of course the above column types contain no object, so what `.applymap(type)` should return, would certainly only depend on the column type, but what I originally wanted, is include guardian code (like an assertion) in my data generation method, which works parametrized and could create other column types as well. The code was meant to check if something unexpected slips in my dataframe in the generation process (which according the original message happened), in order to identify these cases and beeing able to fix them.

Comment: No idea but the error message itself means that you're trying to call a dtype object. For example `import numpy as np; np.dtype(float)(5.0)` will fail with the same error message. In this example, `np.dtype(float)` describes how a float is stored such as the size (e.g. `np.dtype(float).itemsize == 8`) but what you probably want is the actual float itself (e.g. `float(5.0)`). Maybe a similar thing will apply for your problem.

Comment: Hi @KentShikama, thank you for the feedback. But in my case I don't call anything similar. It almost seems, that there is a bug or maybe a version incompatibilty.